# Possible to reduce the length of CloudWatch line prefix? (Remove date being displayed twice)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-code-deploy

AWS CodeDeploy logs with CloudWatch use a line prefix that's extraordinarily long, and the config doesn't seem to suggest many options on changing it. Each line has this long prefix:

```bash
2023-12-26T23:08:53.225000+00:00 i-0b012e086328bb031-cdlog [2023-12-26 23:08:52.145] [d-2A94MPLJ2][stdout]
```

Is it possible to alter the config to not show the date/time twice? This is an example of the config I use to start CloudWatch logging

```bash
date=$(date +'%Y/%m/%d/%R')

echo "Stopping cloudwatch agent"
/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -m ec2 -a stop

cd /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.d

# works
echo "{\"agent\": {\"metrics_collection_interval\": 10,\"logfile\": \"/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/deployment-logs/codedeploy-agent-deployments.log\"},\"logs\": { \"logs_collected\": {\"files\": {\"collect_list\": [{\"file_path\": \"/var/log/aws/codedeploy-agent/codedeploy-agent.log\",\"log_group_name\": \"codedeploy-agent-log\",\"log_stream_name\": \"{instance_id}-cdlog\"},{\"file_path\": \"/tmp/codedeploy-agent.update.log\", \"log_group_name\": \"codedeploy-updater-log\", \"log_stream_name\": \"{instance_id}-codedeploy-updater-log\" },{\"file_path\": \"/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/deployment-logs/codedeploy-agent-deployments.log\", \"log_group_name\": \"codedeploy-deployments-log\", \"log_stream_name\": \"{instance_id}-cdlog\"} ] }},\"log_stream_name\": \"codedeploy_firehawk_deploy\",\"force_flush_interval\": 15}}" >>cloudwatch.cfg

echo "Starting cloudwatch agent"
/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a fetch-config -m ec2 -c file:cloudwatch.cfg -s
```